# How to use MPMedaPickerController on swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'm simply trying to get it so that when you press a button, you display the user's music library, and then you can select a song. I've found that the way to do this is through `MPMediaPickerController` but I've been struggling to get it to work. This is what my program looks like so far:

```
import MediaPlayer
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
 var mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController?


override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func showSongs(_ sender: Any) {
    displayMediaPicker()
}
func displayMediaPicker() {
    mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)
    if let picker = mediaPicker {
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        picker.showsCloudItems = false
        picker.prompt = "Please Pick a Song" 
        view.addSubview(picker.view)
        }
}

}
```

I know that there should be a property `[self presentViewController:picker animated: true completion:nil]` after `view.addSubview(picker.view)`, but when I type it I have the options `presentingViewController` & `presentedViewContoller`, but no `presentViewController`

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The function `presentViewController: animated: completion:` function was renamed in Swift 3 so now it looks like this:

`present(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)`

So, in your case you'd end up with a `presentPicker` function looking something like this (notice the last line):

```
func presentPicker() {
    mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)
    if let picker = mediaPicker {
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        picker.showsCloudItems = false
        picker.prompt = "Please Pick a Song"
        present(picker, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5, Swift 4 Very simple solution

```
//MARK:- add it in your info.plist file
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key> 
<string>$(app Name) uses music</string>

//MARK:- Import in your file
import MediaPlayer

//MARK:- Import as your Delegates
MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate


//MARK:- Just call this function 
func openAudio()
{
    let audiopicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .anyAudio)
    audiopicker.prompt = "Audio"
    audiopicker.delegate = self
    audiopicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    self.present(audiopicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```